# Limitation of converting pointer to one type to pointer to another type

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer

I'm experiencing some troubles with understanding convertation of "pointer to" types. Let me provide some examples:

```
struct test{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

1.

```
void *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
struct test *test_ptr = ptr;   //OK 7.22.3(p1)
int x = test_ptr -> x;         //UB 6.2.6.1(p4)
```

2.

```
void *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct test) + 1);
struct test *test_ptr = ptr + 1; //UB 6.3.2.3(p7)
```

3.

```
void *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct test) + 1);
struct test *test_ptr = ptr; //OK 7.22.3(p1)
int x = test_ptr -> x; //Unspecified behavior or also UB?
```

My understaing of the cases:

1. The pointer convertation returned by `malloc` is ok by itself as 7.22.3(p1):

> The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so
>   that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a
>   fundamental alignment requirement

The accessing is incorrect because the `test_ptr` cannot point to a valid `struct test_ptr` object since its size is less then the one allocated with `malloc` causing UB as explained at 6.2.6.1(p4).

2. This is UB since we cannot say anything about alignment of `ptr + 1` pointer. 6.3.2.3(p7) explains this:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a
>   different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly
>   aligned68) for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

**How is case 3 explained in the Standard?**

It is unspecified in the standard (at least I could not find) if it is valid to convert a pointer to an object with no declared type to a pointer to an object whose size is less then the one allocated object has? (I'm not considering the array allocation here like `malloc(10 * sizeof(struct test));` which is clearly explained at 7.22.3(p1)). 6.2.6.1(p4) states:

> Values stored in non-bit-field objects of any other object type
>   consist of n × CHAR_BIT bits, where n is the size of an object of that
>   type, in bytes.

The allocated object does not consist of `sizeof(struct test) x CHAR_BIT` bits, but `(sizeof(struct test) + 1) x CHAR_BIT`

Comment: Regarding case 3, there's nothing special about it. It's really no different from `struct test *test_ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct test) + 1);`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was confused by the fact that the valid object of type `struct test` has size `sizeof(struct test)` -- no more, no less. But the size of the object allocated with `malloc(sizeof(struct test) + 1)` is `sizeof(struct test) + 1` which is different.

Comment: `sizeof(struct test) - 1` would be bad, but allocating more memory than needed is okay. It might be a waste of memory, but it doesn't hurt anything else.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not UB to point out of bounds, only to deference out of bounds. So case #2 may not be considered UB.

Comment: Although I suppose `ptr + 1` is a one byte increment as a GNU extension. Arithmetic on void pointers is UB.. since I last checked.

Comment: @okovko Probably right, point out of bounds is not an UB by itself. The problem with #2 is that I'm converting incorrectly alligned `void *` to `struct test*`

Comment: @okovko _ptr + 1 is a one byte increment_ Not really GNU extension. It's defined at 6.2.5(p28) `A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type`. so I don't think `void *` arithemtic is UB.

Comment: @SomeName: the real question is: why do you think that `malloc(x+1)` would be aligned differently from `malloc(x)`?

Comment: @Groo alignment of `malloc(x+1)` is okay. But alignment of `malloc(x+1) + 1` is undefined.

Comment: @SomeName Oh cool, thanks for letting me know. I think that's a relatively new part of the standard. Well, I could be mistaken.

Comment: @SomeName Feel free to select my answer as the accepted answer if you found it useful or sufficient. I want to hit 1k! :P

Comment: @SomeName: ok, but `malloc(x+1) + 1` is UB because `malloc` returns `void*`. If you're using gnu extensions then it's presumably aligned on the next byte. But I was referring to your third example, `malloc(sizeof(struct test) + 1)`, since first two examples wrote about alignment, I didn't understand your concerns.

Comment: @Groo But `void*` and `char*` can be used interchangeably so I thought we can use `void*` in exactly the same way as `char*`... Can we?

Comment: No, according to the standard, you cannot perform pointer arithmetic on `void*`, although you would need `-Wpedantic` on gcc to [get the error](https://godbolt.org/z/KWg_Av). `void*` is special in the sense that you can implicitly cast from and to any other pointer, while `char*` is special because it is the only one which is allowed to alias other pointers (apart from `void*` obviously) and allows pointer arithmetic like all other pointers. So if you want to pass an "anonymous" pointer around, use `void*`. If you need to iterate through individual bytes of an object, cast to `char*`.

Comment: @Groo does it mean that we can cast the `void*` to `char*` then add 1 to it and then cast it back to `void*`. I think this is possible since the Standard guarantees that `void*` and `char` has the same representation and alignment requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be legal because in C we have [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member).

```
typedef struct flex_s {
  int x;
  int arr[];
} flex_t;
void *ptr = malloc(sizeof(flex_t) + sizeof(int));
flex_t *flex = ptr;
flex->arr[0]; // legal
```

So, if you want an answer from the standard, look at its definition of flexible array members and their allocation, and the rule will be given.

You can start by taking a look at example 20 of page 114 of [the free draft of C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf).